Trying to implement Accordion in React so that multiple accordions can be open at a time
I am sending data as an array of object from main  component file to Accordion component -
return <Accordion items={items} />;
items consist of 3 properties - Id, title and data.
Accordion component receives all data and then displays in the browser-


function Accordion({ items }) {
  const [expandedId, setExpandedId] = useState("");

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    if (expandedId === id) {
      setExpandedId("");
    } else {
      setExpandedId(id);
    }

    //console.log(id);
  };

  const renderedItem = items.map((item) => {
    const isExpanded = expandedId === item.id;
    const content = isExpanded && <div>{item.data}</div>;
    const icon = <span>{isExpanded ? 'iconOpen' : 'iconClosed'}</span>;

    return (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <div onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}>
          {item.title}
          {icon}
        </div>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  });
  return <div>{renderedItem}</div>;
}

export default Accordion;

Issue with this solution is this I am able to implement Accordion but only one accordion is opening at a time. If I click on other Accordion, the one that was opened gets closed.
I am aware that this can be implemented if I send a single data from main component to Accordion component like this -
Main.js

   <div>
      {items.map(({ id, title, data }) => (
        <Accordion key={id} title={title} data={data} />
      ))}
    </div>

Accordion.js

function Accordion({ id, title, data }) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const icon = <span>{isExpanded ? 'iconOpen' : 'iconClosed'}</span>;

  return (
    <div key={id}>
      <div onClick={() => setActive(!active)}>
        {title}
        {icon}
      </div>
      {active && <div>{data}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Accordion;

But I want to handle all logic in Accordion component and not depending upon main component to send data via prop one by one

Your accordion should be a single accordion item, and you should have another component that is a list of accordions, then the list of accordions have an array of ids.

I have implemented the solution that you described and mentioned the same in my question too. But I want the logic to be handled in one component only.
